# C# TextBox NewLine simulate Ctrl+Enter on KeyDownEvent

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, textbox, newline

I have a `TextBox` (multiline) and if I press `Ctrl+Enter` it just makes a new line. But I would also like to do this on `Shift+Enter`.
I tried:

```
messageTextBox_KeyDown(null, new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Control | Keys.Enter));
```

But this is not working.

I think that I can do this:

```
int lastSelectionStart = messageTextBox.SelectionStart;
messageTextBox.Text = messageTextBox.Text.Insert(messageTextBox.SelectionStart, Environment.NewLine);
messageTextBox.SelectionStart = lastSelectionStart;
```

But I don't like this.

How can I make it so that Shift+Enter will be the same as Ctrl+Enter?

My current code:

KeyDownEvent

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    if (e.Shift)
    {

    }
    else if (!e.Control)
    {
        sendButton_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

In KeyPress event:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

This is because I want to use the Enter key alone as Send button.

Comment: It might not be such a great idea to change the default behaviour. I believe that users have come to expect that a multi-line textbox allows them to just press enter if they want to go to a new line.

Comment: I don't think so. Look on the facebook chat. New line is Shift+Enter and alone Enter is used as Send key. I'd like the same.

Comment: Yeah, it would make sense in a chat application, but not necessarily in a standard web form.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like the real problem you are fighting is the form's AcceptButton property.  You cannot fix this with the KeyDown event handler, the keystroke is processed *before* it ever gets to the event.

This can be fixed by overriding the form's ProcessCmdKey() method but the cleanest way is to just create your own TextBox derived control.  You can override its IsInputKey() method to tell Winforms that you want to see the Ctrl+Enter key.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox.  Note how you can alter the class to your convenience to make it more adept at being a chat input box.

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

```
class ChatBox : TextBox {
    public ChatBox() {
        this.Multiline = true;
    }
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter)) return true;
        return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
    }
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter)) {
            int pos = this.SelectionStart;
            this.SelectedText = Environment.NewLine;
            this.SelectionStart = pos;
            e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            return;
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thats exactly what have on my mind and also it's in my question. But if there is no easy way how simulate exactly Ctrl+Enter I'll do it this way. One note to your code SelectionStart need to be as this: `messageTextBox.SelectionStart = lastSelectionStart + Environment.NewLine.Length;` and also `ScrollToCaret();`

Comment: You'd need pinvoke to let the native control see a different keystroke.  That's certainly best avoided when it isn't necessary.